# design a macro that replaces \divide

Tags: macros

One of
the arithmetic instructions (`\divide`) does not even have an equivalent in standard
LaTeX.
The inx expressions can be used in arguments to macros (the `calc` package
doesn't employ category code changes to achieve its goals)

Comment: ... and the question is? `\newcommand\mydivide[3]{\edef#1{\number\numexpr(#2)/(#3)\relax}}` will divide the second by the third argument and store the result in a macro whose name is the first argument.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of libraries that can be used for calculations with LaTeX perhaps the best being the `fp` package. There is also an equivalent available in LaTeX3. To divide you type:

```
   \FPdiv\result{3}{7}
```

With the result being available in `\result`.

Here is a full minimal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\FPdiv\result{3}{7}
\result
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be the implementation of `\divide` in LaTeX:

```
\newcommand{\dividecounter}[2]{%
  \global\divide\csname c@#1\endcsname#2\relax}
```

Now `\dividecounter{page}{3}` will store in the counter `page` the result of the division.

Similarly one could implement `\multiply`. But LaTeX counters are not meant for doing arithmetic, but rather to index something. TeX counters should be used for (local) arithmetic manipulations.